# Ускорение обработки изображений OpenCV

Tags: c++, изображения, opencv

История такая. В программе понадобился урезанный редактор для изображений, в котором есть ползунки, меняющие значение для гаммы, контраста и т.д. Обрабатываемые изображения имеют размер порядка 6000 на 4000 пикселей. Все бы ничего, но обработка, например, гаммы затягивается на пол секунды, но с некоторой хитростью сокращается вдвое. Например гамма:

```
        QTime time;
        time.start();
        double gamma = 0.5;
        double G = 1/gamma;

        double preCalc[256];

        for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
        {
            preCalc[i] =  pow((i / 255.0), G) * 255; // для ускорения просчитываем все заранее (чтобы не повторять это вычисление миллионы раз вместо 255)
        }


        for( int y = 0; y < tempImg.rows; y++ )
        {
            for( int x = 0; x < tempImg.cols; x++ )
            {
                for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
                {
                    tempImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[c] =
                    cv::saturate_cast<uchar>( preCalc[tempImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[c]] );
                }
            }
        }
        qDebug() << time.elapsed();
```

В результате, насчитывается 1/3 секунды. А представьте, добавим еще расчет яркости контрастности все... А фотошоп это изображение обрабатывает в реальном времени при изменении ползунка вне зависимости от масштаба. Я, конечно, не забываю, что ребята в ADOBE очень многое могут. Вопрос в том, какую хитрость они применили? Т.к. дело происходит на ноутбуке и я не уверен, что используется gpu.

Comment: Ребята применили SSE.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov допустим, SSE это регистры процессора, позволяющие производить несколько арифметических операций одновременно. А где у меня вычисления? По факту работа только с памятью. На самом деле, после того как задал вопрос, случайно в комментарии на хабре узнал, что в таких продуктах сначала обрабатывается preview

Comment: Представьте, что во всем этом деле получается около 70 млн операций (6000 * 4000 * 3(RGB))

Comment: Подведу итог. Изображение 1200 на 800 обрабатывается 0.014 секунды. Т.е. необходимо колхозить алгоритмы обработки preview. Еще можно обсудить вопрос с gpu